# Redirection of website-want to use /en folder being redirected to post

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I encountered a strange behaviour with WordPress website.

I have created /en folder in the root and want to have another WordPress website there.

The problems appears when I try to open mainwebsite.com/en I'm being redirected to mainwebsite.com/english-post

So, WP gives the priority to the post that is found in the main domain and it's slug begins with "en".

I tried changing the folders name to "ren" and the website in the folder than shows up nicely.

I've checked .htaccess file for some redirects and none is set.

I noticed that this is a typical WP behaviour, as I tested on some "bigger" brands that use WP and same thing happens,ie:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/en redirects to --> https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/enabling-multiscreen-tracking-with-google-analytics/

http://vanheusen.com/en redirects to --> http://vanheusen.com/products/english_shaded_box_silk_tie/

Have any idea how to solve this?

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(en/)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please can you edit your post and include your root `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: what does your .htaccess have in it inside the /en folder?

Comment: @PanamaJack It's a clone of the main website so it does have exactly the same

Comment: You're going to have to change the .htaccess or it's not going to work correctly

Comment: @PanamaJack any suggestions maybe, what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rule in your main .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And then you need this rule below in the .htaccess inside **en** folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /en/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Let me know how this works